# Need help in correcting login response to GT06 GPS device in Java

Tags: java, gps

I am able to read GT06 data on our Linux server, i can only see Login requests on the server but not able to see location data at every 10 seconds which i had set. After reading articles, blog and forum i came to know that i need to pass the response to my request. I have sent response with values which mentioned in the protocol document but could not get location data. then follow Traccar documents and applied CRC-ITU check method but still not getting location data.

**Login requests from device**

```
78 78 0D 01     03 58 51 10 22 63 63 06     00 04       BA B6       0D 0A
78 78 0D 01     03 58 51 10 22 63 63 06     00 06       99 A4       0D 0A
78 78 0D 01     03 58 51 10 22 63 63 06     00 08       70 DA       0D 0A
78 78 0D 01     03 58 51 10 22 63 63 06     00 0A       53 C8       0D 0A
78 78 0D 01     03 58 51 10 22 63 63 06     00 0C       36 FE       0D 0A
78 78 0D 01     03 58 51 10 22 63 63 06     00 0E       15 EC       0D 0A
78 78 0D 01     03 58 51 10 22 63 63 06     00 10       EC 13       0D 0A
```

**Resonse sent by Server**

```
78 78 05 01 00 11 C9 5D 0D 0A
78 78 05 01 00 0F 30 A2 0D 0A
78 78 05 01 00 0D 13 B0 0D 0A
```

I have used following two method to generate response from server.

```
    private byte[] getLoginResponse(byte[] req){
    byte[] b = new byte[4];
    byte[] bResponse = new byte[10];
    b[0] = 0x05;
    b[1] = req[3];
    b[2] = req[req[2] - 6 + 5];
    b[3] = req[req[2] -5 + 5];

    short x = crc16Ccitt(b);
    bResponse[0] = 0x78;
    bResponse[1] = 0x78;
    bResponse[2] = 0x05;
    bResponse[3] = req[3];
    bResponse[4] = req[req[2] - 6 + 5];
    bResponse[5] = req[req[2] -5 + 5];
    bResponse[6] = (byte) ((x >> 8) & 0xff);;
    bResponse[7] = (byte) (x & 0xff);
    bResponse[8] = 0x0D;
    bResponse[9] = 0x0A;
    return bResponse;
}



public  short crc16Ccitt(byte[] bytes) {
    int crc = 0xFFFF;          // initial value
    int polynomial = 0x1021;   // 0001 0000 0010 0001 (0, 5, 12)

    for (byte b : bytes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            boolean bit = ((b   >> (7-i) & 1) == 1);
            boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15    & 1) == 1);
            crc <<= 1;
            if (c15 ^ bit) crc ^= polynomial;
        }
    }

    crc &= 0xffff;
    return (short) crc;
}
```

can you please tell me what is wrong with this, why not getting location data continuously.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static byte[] getLoginResponse(){
          byte[] respBuffer = new byte[10];
        byte[] tmprespBuffer = new byte[4];

      respBuffer[0] = (byte)(0x78);
      respBuffer[1] = (byte)(0x78);


      //Length:
      respBuffer[2] = (byte)(0x05);
      tmprespBuffer[0] = (byte)(0x05);

      //Profotcol
      respBuffer[3] = (byte)(0x01);
      tmprespBuffer[1] = (byte)(0x01);

      //Serial No
      respBuffer[4] =  (byte)(0x00);
      respBuffer[5] =  (byte)(0x01);

      tmprespBuffer[2] =(byte)(0x00);
      tmprespBuffer[3] = (byte)(0x01);

      //CRC Check...
      String crc = new Crc16().getCRC(tmprespBuffer);

      respBuffer[6] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(crc.substring(0,2), 16);
      respBuffer[7] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(crc.substring(2,4).toString(), 16);



      respBuffer[8] = (byte) 0x0D ;
      respBuffer[9] = (byte) 0x0A ;


        return respBuffer;
    }

    private static byte[] getStatuesResponse(){
          byte[] respBuffer = new byte[10];
      byte[] tmprespBuffer = new byte[4];

    respBuffer[0] = (byte)(0x78);
    respBuffer[1] = (byte)(0x78);


    //Length:
    respBuffer[2] = (byte)(0x05);
    tmprespBuffer[0] = (byte)(0x05);

    //Profotcol
    respBuffer[3] = (byte)(0x13);
    tmprespBuffer[1] = (byte)(0x13);

    //Serial No
    respBuffer[4] =  (byte)(0x00);
    respBuffer[5] =  (byte)(0x01);

    tmprespBuffer[2] =(byte)(0x00);
    tmprespBuffer[3] = (byte)(0x01);

    //CRC Check...
    String crc = new Crc16().getCRC(tmprespBuffer);

    respBuffer[6] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(crc.substring(0,2), 16);
    respBuffer[7] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(crc.substring(2,4).toString(), 16);



    respBuffer[8] = (byte) 0x0D ;
    respBuffer[9] = (byte) 0x0A ;


        return respBuffer;
    }

public class Crc16 {

      //private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Crc16.class);

      public static void main(String[] args){

          byte b[] = new byte[13] ;

         // b[0] = (byte) 0x78;
         // b[1] = (byte) 0x78;
         // 24 24 00 11 13 61 23 45 67 8f ff 50 00 05 d8 0d 0a
          b[0] = (byte) 0x24;
          b[1] = (byte) 0x24;
          b[2] = (byte) 0x00;
          b[3] = (byte) 0x11;
          b[4] = (byte) 0x13;
          b[5] = (byte) 0x61;
          b[6] = (byte) 0x23;
          b[7] = (byte) 0x45;
          b[8] = (byte) 0x67;
          b[9] = (byte) 0x8f;
          b[10] = (byte) 0xff;
          b[11] = (byte) 0x50;
          b[12] = (byte) 0x00;



          System.out.println(new Crc16().getCRC(b));
          System.out.println(new Crc16().CRC16CCITT(b));
      }

      public String getCRC(byte bytes[]){

          int crc = 0xffff;

          try{

          int[] table = {

                0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
                0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
                0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
                0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
                0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
                0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
                0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
                0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
                0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
                0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
                0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
                0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
                0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
                0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
                0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
                0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
                0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
                0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
                0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
                0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
                0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
                0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
                0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
                0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
                0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
                0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
                0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
                0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
                0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
                0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
                0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
                0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78

            };



            for (byte b : bytes) {

               // System.out.println((crc ^ b) & 0xff);
                crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ b) & 0xff];
            }


            crc = ~crc;

            }catch(Exception ex){
             // log.error(ex);
          }

            return Integer.toHexString(crc).substring(4,8);

      }

      public String CRC16CCITT(byte bytes[])
      {
       int crc = 0xFFFF;          // initial value
            int polynomial = 0x1021;   // 0001 0000 0010 0001  (0, 5, 12)

            // byte[] testBytes = "123456789".getBytes("ASCII");

           // byte[] bytes = args[0].getBytes();

            for (byte b : bytes) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    boolean bit = ((b   >> (7-i) & 1) == 1);
                    boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15    & 1) == 1);
                    crc <<= 1;
                    if (c15 ^ bit) crc ^= polynomial;
                 }
            }

            crc &= 0xffff;
            System.out.println("CRC16-CCITT = " + Integer.toHexString(crc));
            return Integer.toHexString(crc);
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String md5(String s) {
        try 
        {
            MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            m.update(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length());
            BigInteger i = new BigInteger(1,m.digest());
            return String.format("%1$032x", i);         
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }



}
```